# Background-process and flask

Tags: python, flask, background-process

So, I'm pretty new at webapp development and I'm currently building a simple blog engine for learning purposes using python/flask.

I don't have much problems so far except for a new feature I would like to implement: post a new entry by email.

To implement this, I figure I need to have a background process checking multiple emails accounts for new posts. When a new email is found, the process would go and create the new post to be displayed by the fornt-end.

I hope this is correct and if so, I can I go about implementing this?

Might be relevant but I'm using sqlalchemy.

Thanks

Comment: I think it can be done. You can build up a email server on your server or fetch the emails from your existing email account, for example gmail. There are already some modules in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I would use one of the incoming mail APIs for this instead of trying to hack something together.  For example, the Sendgrid API will accept an email and then POST some JSON to your app.

With this fake Post class:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    text = TextProperty()
    title = TextProperty()
```

You could have a view like this:

```
@app.route('/hook/new-email/', methods=['POST'])
def new_email():
    envelope = json.loads(request.form.get('envelope'))
    to_address = envelope['to'][0]
    from_address = envelope['from']
    text = request.form.get('text')
    subject = request.form.get('subject')

    if from_address == settings.ACCEPTED_AUTHOR:
        post = Post(text=text, title=subject)
        post.put()
```

Remember that if you allow posts to be authored by simple email, you are going to have to do some sort of checking to make sure that you are not posting each and every spam email you get.

Comment: That would indeed do it. As a way to learn though, how could I go on about doing it by myself?